# Syntastic fail when using Windows Python in Vim

Tags: python, windows, vim, cygwin, vim-syntastic

I use vim on windows, from cygwin.

I changed the PYthon used to be Windows Python, ie my .bashrc includes:

```
  PATH=/cygdrive/c/Python27:$PATH
```

This causes the syntastic plugin to fail, as Windows Python does not deal with the /cygdrive/c/ prefix instead of C:/ :

```
syntastic: error: checker output:
C:\Python27\python.exe: can't open file '/cygdrive/c/[path to my .vim folder]/.vim/bundle/syntastic/syntax_checkers/python/compile.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

As far as I understand it, the solution would be somehow to change filepaths starting with /cygwin/c/ when the cygwin terminal is calling Windows Python.

How one may do that?

Comment: Why do you need _Windows_ _Python_ in the 1st place? You install _Cygwin_ if you need a _Ux_ like interface. _Cygwin_ comes with its own _Python (27)_.

Comment: Your first problem is the incorrect use of `shellslash` (cf. `:h syntastic-shellslash`).  There are probably others.